# GooglePlacesAutocomplete doesn't take tap on results

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, scrollview, react-google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to use the react-native-google-places-autocomplete library and its component GooglePlacesAutocomplete, on a react-native project using expo (sdk 49).

This in normal screens works normally, the problem is when I use it in a screen that has a ScrollView as parent...
This is because in order to avoid the error **The complete error is: VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead**, I am forced to embed the component in an additional ScrollView of horizontal type, also using a relative position and high zIndex to make sure that I always have an "overlap" of the results of this component on the others.
So the final component I use in my screen where I need it is:

```
    <ScrollView
      horizontal={true}
      // nestedScrollEnabled={true}
      // keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
      contentContainerStyle={{
        position: 'relative',
        elevation: 100,
        zIndex: 100,
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
      }}
    >
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        placeholder={placeholder}
        fetchDetails
        onPress={(data, details) => handlePress(data, details!)}
        query={{
          key: process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_MAPS_KEY,
          language: 'en',
        }}
        // keepResultsAfterBlur
      />
    </ScrollView>
```

Now the problem is that once I click on a result, it is (probably) perceived as a tap on the main scrollview, so not only does GooglePlacesAutocomplete not take the result I clicked, it also closes the results bar.

I am almost sure of this problem, because if instead of clicking, I manually close the simulator keyboard first, the places do not disappear and if I click one, it is selected correctly.

Another workaround I have found is to use the prop "keepResultsAfterBlur," which, however, as the name implies, keeps the results even once a location is selected, and thus is impractical.
How can I solve it permanently?